# TIBCO EMS Load Testing using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-designer

I have created a JMS Point-to-Point Request Response test as documented in the JMeter manual.

If  my message properties are set to request only, the test results to success, however when I switch to request/reply sometimes the test success and fails. Any configurations that i may be missing?

My JMeter Point-to-Point Configuration:

[Jmeter Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmN9h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screen shot showing the JMeter configuration it seems you are using the same queue to manage requests and replies. You should use two different queues for request / reply to work properly.